# SQL SERVER 2016 R Services -- SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: sql, r, database-connection, sql-server-2016

I was trying to learn the new feature -- R in SQL Server 2016 and I was following this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/SQL-Server-R-Services-Samples/tree/master/RetailForecasting/SQLR) as example.

I set up SQLRUserGroup as a new login and was able to run some R scripts, but the data_preprocess_score.sql gives me the following error message and it looked like related to connection.

Here is what I tried to call the sproc:

```
EXEC data_preprocess_score @testlength = 1, @id1value = 2, @id2value = 1,
    @connectionString = 'SERVER=.;DATABASE=Test;Trusted_Connection=true;`'
```

Below is the error message:

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 1
A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
```

An external script error occurred:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
Calls: source ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> doTryCatch -> .Call
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(tsvalues, value.threshold) : '>' not meaningful for factors

Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information.
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
Execution halted
```

STDOUT message(s) from external script:

```
Rows Read: 166, Total Rows Processed: 166Caught exception in file: CxAnalysis.cpp, line: 6488. ThreadID: 14112 Rethrowing.

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Connection not open

ODBC Error in SQLDisconnect
Caught exception in file: CxAnalysis.cpp, line: 5682. ThreadID: 14112 Rethrowing.
Caught exception in file: CxAnalysis.cpp, line: 5249. ThreadID: 14112 Rethrowing.
```

Can someone help me with this error? 
Thanks!

Comment: try using `(local)` or `localhost` in place of the full stop for the `SERVER=` parameter

Comment: Thanks @cha, I tried but it still gave me the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Driver=SQL Server` to the front of your connection string. It wouldn't hurt to set `Server=localhost` too.

```
EXEC data_preprocess_score @testlength = 1, @id1value = 2, @id2value = 1,
    @connectionString = 'Driver=SQL Server;SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=Test;Trusted_Connection=true;'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run R scripts to get data, but get the following error with when writing data with rx functions like rxPredict/rxDataStep:

> DBNETLIB; SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Then, you may be hitting an issue with loop back connections to SQL Server from R script. Please check the following configurations required for loop back connections:

1. Implied Authentication for Launchpad Accounts is enabled using instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt696069.aspx#Anchor_2)
2. TCP/IP client protocol is enabled for the Server using instructions [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181035(v=sql.110).aspx)

Specifically in your case, please check for the TCP/IP protocol configuration, since you mentioned the login for SQLRUserGroup was created.